# VBA CopyFolder copying wrong folder

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a small macro that is supposed to copy a folder and all its contents from one filepath to another.  The problem is, it's copying the wrong folder.  It instead copies the first subfolder (but not its contents) from that folder and then errors out with a "Path not found" error.  Occasionally it will copy the main folder and then just that same first subfolder with none of its contents and then again error out with "Path not found".

```
   Dim strFilePath As String, techfolder As String

   strFilePath = "G:\Data\FolderName\PROJECTS\2019\AnotherFolderName\Test_Area\" & year2 & " - Testing\6. Verification\" & quarter & "\3 - Verification Emails Received\YetAnotherFolderName"

   techfolder = "G:\Data\CompanyName\FolderName\AnotherFolderName\Name" & year2 & " " & quarter2 & "\Completed\"

       Dim FSO As Object

               If Right(techfolder, 1) = "\" Then
                   techfolder = Left(techfolder, Len(techfolder) - 1)
               End If

               If Right(strFilePath, 1) = "\" Then
                   strFilePath = Left(strFilePath, Len(strFilePath) - 1)
               End If

           Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

               If FSO.FolderExists(techfolder) = False Then
                   MsgBox techfolder & " doesn't exist"
                   Exit Sub
               End If
   Debug.Print (strFilePath)
   Debug.Print (techfolder)
            FSO.CopyFolder Source:=techfolder, Destination:=strFilePath
           MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & techfolder & " in " & strFilePath
```

I've tried a couple different methods of the CopyFolder with if logic, etc. from some internet searches but all in this general form. None of them copy the folder and all its subfolders/contents correctly.

I've checked my filepaths via the debug, they are fine and I can copy/paste them into file explorer and navigate with no issue.  Additionally the subfolder copying implies that it seems to be correct.

Manually copying the folder or its subfolder has no issues.

ETA:  There are about 31 sub folders and each contains one excel and one pdf.

Variable Values are:

Quarter is Q3 2018
Year2 is 2018
Quarter2 is Q3

Year2 and Quarter2 are made by substrings of Quarter, a variable that is populated via an inputbox.

```
   year2 = Mid(quarter, 4, 4)
   quarter2 = Mid(quarter, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Your code works for me at least with some test directores and files I created. Are the folder names extremely long?

Comment: The longest is around 53 characters; but that one's further down in the list.  It isn't even making it that far.  The main folder name is "Completed" and that's not even getting copied sometimes.  Sometimes it just goes straight to the sub-folder which is in the format  "REQ-#### Firstname Lastname"

Comment: Do you use any wildcards in one of the pathnames?

Comment: No, I use some variable calls for year/quarter, but no wildcards.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the actual values of `strFilePath` and `techfolder` to your posting? Maybe this gives a clue. Otherwise I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: I edited to include.  I changed some values, but what I changed was simple text to a different simple text to maintain confidentiality.

Comment: Could you also add values for the variable? I tested with `year2=2019` and `quarert="I" : quarter2="II"`. Worked fine for me.

Comment: Added to end of post.  They are all string values.

Comment: Ok, I am out of ideas. I created some test directories based on your values and put some files there. Copying works fine.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for looking into it.  I'm wondering if it's maybe some weird security thing on the directory.  I'll keep messing with it.  Maybe I'll stumble on to something!